# NPM add from private repo fails with permission denied when it's from an existing project

Tags: node.js, git, docker, github, npm

I've been trying to debug this super weird issue. Got a project where I am trying to install a private repository with the `npm` command.

This does not work when it's in an existing project but does when it's a newly created project that's just been created with `npm init`.

The existing project is in `/app` and the new project is in `/opt` (for testing purposes)

Running `npm add git+ssh://git@github.com:company/repository.git` in `/app` returns with:

```log
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/company/repository.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-11-24T00_25_10_559Z-debug.log
```

Running the exact same command from the `/opt` project installs the package correctly without any issues.

I'm running this from an alpine docker box with `openssh` installed.

This is the `Dockerfile`

```docker
FROM node:16.13-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-client git python2

RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts && ln -s /run/secrets/ssh_key ~/.ssh/id_rsa && ln -s /run/secrets/ssh_pub_key ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app
```

A few more informative stuff

```sh
/app # node -v
v16.13.0
/app # npm -v
8.1.4
/app # ssh -T git@github.com
Hi AzaZPPL! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

`package.json`

```json
{
    "name": "project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nuxt",
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "start": "nuxt start",
        "generate": "nuxt generate",
        "generate-schema": "node apollo/generate-schema.js",
        "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .eslintignore .",
        "lintfix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .eslintignore ."
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@nuxtjs/apollo": "^4.0.1-rc.4",
        "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.9.1",
        "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.2",
        "@nuxtjs/dayjs": "^1.2.1",
        "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.0.0",
        "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
        "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.3.1",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "date-fns": "^2.19.0",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "filepond": "^4.27.1",
        "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type": "^1.2.6",
        "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "^4.6.6",
        "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
        "js-file-download": "^0.4.12",
        "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.20",
        "nuxt": "^2.14.6",
        "nuxt-buefy": "^0.4.10",
        "nuxt-i18n": "^6.15.4",
        "vee-validate": "^3.4.3",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-filepond": "^6.0.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.3",
        "eslint": "^7.12.1",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
        "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.1.0",
        "prettier": "^2.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.8",
        "sass-loader": "^12.3.0"
    }
}
```

Any ideas in what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @VonC's answer I was able to figure out what was going on.

Taking a closer look at the logs, I found out that there is actually a user called `node` which is used when running `npm`. Inside the Dockerfile of the Alpine image this user was being created and `npm` is configured to use this user.

So what happened was whenever I logged into the docker container I was logging in as the `root` user and all the ssh keys which were set in the Dockerfile were being run by the `root` user.

Running the `ssh -T git@github.com` worked because the `root` user was setup correctly but not the `node` user

What I still can't get my head around is why did running the command in the `/opt` folder work? Anyway that's a mystery for a different day.

This is my updated Dockerfile. I set the ssh keys to the `node` user and login as the `node` user

```docker
FROM node:16.13-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache openssh-client git

RUN mkdir /app && chown node:node /app

USER node

RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN ln -s /run/secrets/ssh_key ~/.ssh/id_rsa

WORKDIR /app
```

Answer (score 1):

Try in your Dockerfile to set

```
ENV GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'
```

That should give you more clues as to why your SSH key is or is not considered during `npm add`.